# Runescape ClassNotFoundException. RS2Applet.class

Tags: runescape

So recently I got this problem with Runescape. I have had it for a few months now and I have tried to do many things. I use the Runescape client, but neither the client or website work for me anymore. When I launch the client I get this error - http://prntscr.com/5zd512 and when I attempt to play the game on the website I get this screen - http://prntscr.com/5zd560

The things I have already attempted to do are listed below.

- Disable Windows Firewall
- Allow Java through windows firewall
- Clear Jagex Cache
- Clear Browser Cache
- Clear all browsing data
- Reinstall Java
- Reinstall Opera AND Chrome
- Reinstall RS Client
- Play Oldschool runescape (Still didn't work)
- Lastly, I have already contacted Jagex. I sent a support ticket about 2 months ago. Sadly I still haven't gotten a reply.

Comment: A key piece of information is missing: have you checked whether your internet connection is at fault? Sometimes your access to some online services can be disturbed by a malfunctioning WiFi/Ethernet while other services work.